# Instead of it calling for only the 1 sound, it needs to call for everything in the audioconfig folder and sfx folder. Any help much appreciated?

Tags: lua, game-development, fivem

resource_manifest_version "44febabe-d386-4d18-afbe-5e627f4af937"

files {
'audioconfig/r35sound_game.dat151.rel',

```
'audioconfig/r35sound_sounds.dat54.rel',

'sfx/dlc_r35sound/r35sound.awc',

'sfx/dlc_r35sound/r35sound_npc.awc'
```

}

data_file 'AUDIO_GAMEDATA' 'audioconfig/r35sound_game.dat'

data_file 'AUDIO_SOUNDDATA' 'audioconfig/r35sound_sounds.dat'

data_file 'AUDIO_WAVEPACK' 'sfx/dlc_r35sound'

client_script {

```
'vehicle_names.lua'
```

}

Comment: provide more context, link any reference manuals...

Comment: and please fix the formatting, use a single code block.